# return match item only from array of object mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
[
  {
    item: "journal",
    instock: [
      {
        warehouse: "A",
        qty: 5,
        items: null
      },
      {
        warehouse: "C",
        qty: 15,
        items: [
          {
            name: "alexa",
            age: 26
          },
          {
            name: "Shawn",
            age: 26
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```
db.collection.find({
  "instock.items": {
    $elemMatch: {
      name: "alexa"
    }
  }
})
```

This returns whole items array where as i just want items array with one item {name: 'alexa', age: 26}

Playground Link : https://mongoplayground.net/p/0gB4hNswA6U

Comment: See if this helps, another approach: [play link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hG3r3_BZY3W)

Comment: Hey amibainBeing this is really great  could you please explain your code by posting below

Comment: Done! Posted with explanation. A minor change as well at `$cond` where instead of `$gte`, `$eq` would come since we are filtering on strings and not numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.aggregate(pipeline)` function.

Your code will look like:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $unwind: {
        path: "$instock"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: "$instock.items"
    }
}, {
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$instock.items"
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        name: "alexa"
    }
}])
```

Commands used in this pipeline:

**$unwind** - deconstructs an array of items into multiple documents which all contain the original fields of the original documents except for the unwinded field which now have a value of all the deconstructed objects in the array.

**$replaceRoot** - takes the inner object referenced on `newRoot` and puts it as the document.

**$match** - a way to filter the list of documents you ended up with by some condition. Basically the first argument in the `.find()` function.

For more information about aggregation visit MongoDB's website:

- [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)
- [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)
- [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)
- [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)

**EDIT**

The wanted result was to get single item arrays as a response, to achieve that you can simply remove the `$replaceRoot` stage in the pipeline.

Final pipeline:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $unwind: {
        path: "$instock"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: "$instock.items"
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "instock.items.name": "alexa"
    }
}])
```

Comment: Thank you i edited your code with that i am getting items as object instead of single array item
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$instock"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$instock.items"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "instock.items.name": "alexa"
    }
  }
])

Comment: Ohh yeah, I misread what you wanted to do, I thought you only wanted the object, not a single object array.

Comment: edited one will give an error you will have to replace your $match with  { $match: { "instock.items.name": "alexa" }

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `$elemMatch` in projection section:

```js
db.collection.find({
  // whatever your query is
}, {
  "instock.items": {
    $elemMatch: {
      name: "alexa"
    }
  }
});
```

**UPDATE**

[Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#examples) is a good example of this usage. From the official mongodb documentation.

Comment: i am getting query failed: (BadValue) Cannot use $elemMatch projection on a nested field.


db.collection.find({
  item: "journal"
},
{
  "instock.items": {
    $elemMatch: {
      name: "alexa"
    }
  }
})
playground link : https://mongoplayground.net/p/t6GoB2-tfS0

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach where `$filter` is the key at the project stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "instock.items.name": "alexa"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$instock"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "item": "$item",
      qty: "$instock.qty",
      warehouse: "$instock.warehouse",
      items: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$instock.items",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$item.name",
              "alexa"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      instock: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The idea is to:

- have `$match` as top level filter
- then `$unwind` `instock` array items to prepare for the `$filter`
- Use `$project` for rest of the fields as they are, and use `$filter` on `items` array field
- Finally `$group` them back since `$unwind` was used previously.

[Play link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WR6tnRH9dgi)

Comment: Thank you ambian, btw how $_id is determined that i will be an doc id, and what is $$ROOT

Comment: @Indraraj26 `$_id` refers the `_id` only of the previously unwinded documents, (can't have _id as other field right). [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) is the reference to immediate previous root document as whole [See this example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-documents-by-author). To understand the pipeline I would recommend removing one-one pipeline from the bottom of query and see the o/p what it shows. U'll get it.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, it means a lot to me :)